# Custom Model method

Tags: model, laravel-5.1

Let's suppose I have a models called Car and Image. A car has multiple images, and so I can use the following

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Image')->orderBy('order', 'asc');
}
```

Which is fine when I want to display a gallery. But let's suppose I want the first image from them, I can use this

```
public function firstimg()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Image')->orderBy('order', 'asc')->take(1);
}
```

Which also works well.

Now the question: If a car does not have an image it will return NULL. Instead I would like it to return some default image object, since I would like to avoid checking for it in a view. This is used in many places, which is why I would like to implement it in a model and not in a controller or view. 
How to do it without making too many sql queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a function in your model to return car images in case of existence or return an default image object with default image path like below example function

```
function getCarImages(){
    if( $this->has('images', '>=', 1) ) {
        return $this->images;
    }else{
        $img = new App\Image;
        $img->url = 'path/to/default/image.jpg';
        return $img;
    }
}
```

and i think that your function firstimg should be like that

```
function firstimg(){
    if( $this->has('images', '>=', 1) ) {
        return $this->images->first();
    }else{
        $img = new App\Image;
        $img->url = 'path/to/default/image.jpg';
        return $img;
    }
}
```

hope this help you.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work: "Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation". This is the main problem, I need to return relation not an object

Comment: You can create Image record in the database images table with id for example 1 and when creating a car if not images uploaded for this car associate the default image object record to this car so you now did it as a relation

Comment: Accepted as a solution even though it didn't work directly, it helped me think around the problem and come up with a better solution